# Правильно ли так применять прописные?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Мне хотелось бы узнать, почему постоянно так пишут (например, на сайте «Грамота.ру»). Приведу несколько примеров. *КАК, союз*; *НУ, междометие и частица*. Разве правильно писать вместо кавычек все заглавными буквами? Та же «Грамота» говорила, что только в аббревиатурах могут повторяться заглавные буквы. Так почему они так делают? Еще есть интересный момент. А почему запятая, а не тире?! Почему не *КАК — союз*; не *НУ — междометие и частица*? Очень странно. И правильно ли писать, например, так: *Приставка СУПЕР-*, *Суффикс -ЛИВ-*? Если нет, то как надо?

Comment: Я так делаю, потому что так понятно, без лишних выкрутасов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, о чем вы спрашиваете, относится к особенной сфере — правилам оформления словарей.

• Вот как записаны слова в орфографическом словаре "Грамоты":
[**как**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA)
**ну**, *межд.* и *частица*
**тво́рог**, -а и -у и **творо́г**, творога́ и -у́

Никак во втором примере нельзя поставить тире, так как будет нарушен единый принцип оформления. Поэтому ставится запятая.

• Для толковых же словарей, где очень много информации, "Грамота" использует другие правила (например, слово [**БЫТЬ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C) — там просто некуда ставить тире):

> Словарная статья состоит из заголовочного слова, его грамматической характеристики, рекомендаций по пунктуационному оформлению и иллюстративной зоны. При необходимости статью дополняют зона «Не смешивать!», зона дополнительного комментария, отсылочная зона.
> **Заголовочное слово** указывается в словаре прописными буквами и выделяется полужирным шрифтом. Ударение в заголовочном слове приводится только при необходимости смыслоразличения (**А НУ' КАК**). <...>
> Справа от заголовочной единицы дается помета, указывающая на ее **грамматический класс** или на **употребление в составе синтаксической конструкции**...

В других словарях (например, иностранных слов), где объем объяснений гораздо меньше, иногда, действительно, используется тире:
**ДЕ'НДИ** [англ. dandy] — изысканно одетый светский человек; щеголь, франт.

[Структура словаря](http://lab314.brsu.by/kmp-lite/kmp2/OTT/tLecture/tDictEntry.htm)
[Структура словаря и оформление словарной статьи](https://slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=290#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B2,%2D%2D%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0.) (Новый словарь иностранных слов Захаренко Е. Н., Комаровой Л. Н., Нечаевой И. В.)
[Структура словарной статьи](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-howto) ("Грамота")